# Assuming the Lenstra–Pomerance–Wagstaff conjecture, in what range of values for $p$ would we expect to find the next prime $2^p - 1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures, perfect-numbers

Assuming the [Lenstra–Pomerance–Wagstaff conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_conjectures#Lenstra_Pomerance_Wagstaff_conjecture) is correct, in what range of values for a prime $p$ would we expect to find the next [Mersenne prime](http://www.mersenne.org/primes/) $2^p - 1$?